# Merge [backbone-collections] and [backbone.js-collections]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[backbone.js-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js-collections) and [backbone-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-collections) are about the same thing. I think [backbone.js-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js-collections) should be a synonym of [backbone-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-collections), but the other way around would be fine too.

Comment: Looks right, but since [backbone.js] is the main tag, [backbone.js-collections] should be the one that stays.

Comment: Fair enough. Works for me!